# Contact record is not updating while calling Apex methods imperatively from LWC component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I need to update the `Contact` record with updated field values when the User clicks on the `Save` button. I have created a custom apex method `savePersonalRecord` to update the contact object. And this method is called imperatively from LWC when the user clicks on the Save button. I can see the updated filed values for the contact in the console when I change field values, but the contact record is not updating. I have seen some of the answers online, the code is similar for updating a record. I couldn't identify what is wrong with my code. Could you please help me?  Thanks in Advance!

[image]

**Snapshot when I take out try-catch from Apex method**
[image]

**Apex Controller Method**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Contact getPersonalDetails() {
        Contact contRecord;
    try{
        Id ContId = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()].ContactId;
        for (Contact acct: [SELECT Salutation, FirstName, LastName, Name, Email, MobilePhone, Language__c, Birthdate, Academic_Qualification__c, Department, Title, Industry__c, Area_Of_Interest__c, Additional_Interest__c FROM Contact WHERE Id =: ContId LIMIT 1]){
          contRecord = acct;
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('An exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
        return contRecord;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void savePersonalRecord(Contact personalData){
        try{
            update personalData;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.debug('An exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**JS controller**

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
    import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
    import savePersonalRecord from '@salesforce/apex/MyProfilePageController.savePersonalRecord';
    import getPersonalDetails from '@salesforce/apex/MyProfilePageController.getPersonalDetails';
    import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact'
    import SALUTATION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Salutation';
    import AREA_INTEREST_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Area_Of_Interest__c'; 
    import LANGUAGE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Language__c';
    import ACADEMIC_QUALIFICATION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Academic_Qualification__c';
    
    export default class UpdatePersonalDetails extends LightningElement {
    
    @track personalRecordData;
    
    disableButton;
    areaInterestPicklistValues;
    salutationPicklistValues;
    languagePicklistValues;
    
    @wire(getPersonalDetails) 
    personalDetails ({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.personalRecordData = {...data};
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('Errored:- '+ error.body.message);
        }
    }
    
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;
    
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: SALUTATION_FIELD
      })
      setSalautationObjectInfo({data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.salutationPicklistValues = data.values;
        }
      }  
    
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId", 
        fieldApiName: AREA_INTEREST_FIELD
      })
      setAreaInterestObjectInfo({data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.areaInterestPicklistValues = data.values;
        }
      }    
    
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: LANGUAGE_FIELD
      })
      setLanguageObjectInfo({data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.languagePicklistValues = data.values;
        }
      } 
    
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: ACADEMIC_QUALIFICATION_FIELD
      })
      setAcademicObjectInfo({data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.academicQualifPicklistValues = data.values;
        }
      }

    getHasInvalidFields() {
        const inputComponents = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')];
        inputComponents.forEach((inputComponent) => {
            inputComponent.reportValidity();
        });
        this.hasInvalidFields = inputComponents.some((inputComponent) => inputComponent.checkValidity() === false);
        return this.hasInvalidFields;
    }
    
    displayViewScreen(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('showviewform'));
    }
    
    handleChange(event){
        if(event.target.name === 'salutation'){
            this.personalRecordData.Salutation = event.target.value;
        } else if(event.target.name === 'firstName'){
            this.personalRecordData.FirstName = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'lastName'){
            this.personalRecordData.LastName = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'email'){
            this.personalRecordData.Email = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'mobile'){
            this.personalRecordData.MobilePhone = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'language'){
            this.personalRecordData.Language__c = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'birthDate'){
            this.personalRecordData.Birthdate = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'academicQualification'){
            this.personalRecordData.Academic_Qualification__c = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'jobTitle'){
            this.personalRecordData.Title = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'department'){
            this.personalRecordData.Department = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'industry'){
            this.personalRecordData.Account.Industry = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'areaOfInterest'){
            this.personalRecordData.Area_Of_Interest__c = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'additionalInterests'){
            this.personalRecordData.Additional_Interest__c = event.target.value;
        }
        this.disableButton = this.getHasInvalidFields();
    }
    
    handleSave(){
        console.log('****personalRecordData***', JSON.stringify(this.personalRecordData));
        savePersonalRecord({ personalData: this.personalRecordData})
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                this.displayViewScreen();
            })
             .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
             });
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Take out the try-catch block, that'll give you the error.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thank you very much for your quick reply. When I take out try-catch from the update apex method `savePersonalRecord`, I am getting the below error;

`{status: 500, body: {…}, headers: {…}, ok: false, statusText: 'Server Error', …}`

I have attached a snapshot of the error for your reference.

Comment: So have you clicked on the little (right pointing) arrow on the left of `body: {fieldErrors: {...}...` for a peek?

Comment: btw why are you using too much apex code when everything can be done from LWC only? You can use the lightning record edit form to view and update the same record.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @FelixvanHove. There is no error under `body: {fieldErrors: {...}` . However, I can see an error under, `body: {pageErrors: {...}`.

`pageErrors
: 
Array(1)
0: 
message: "insufficient access rights on object id"
statusCode: "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY"`

Does it mean the user/profile doesn't have access to the `Contact` object?

Comment: It can mean no access to the record, not just profile permissions.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Do we need to change the sharing setting for this Contact object? Currently, the `Default Internal Access` sharing setting of the `Contact` object is `Controlled by Parent`. `Default External Access` is `Private`. The user that I am using to test is a `Customer Community Plus Login` user license user. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: That is likely part of the problem. You can query the UserRecordAccess table to see if the user has access.

Comment: Thank you very much @sfdcfox. When I run the query `SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess` for the UserId and RecordId, the `HasReadAccess` is **true** and `HasEditAccess` is **false**.

Comment: The issue has been resolved by modifying the Sharing settings for the Contact object. Thank you very much @sfdcfox and Felix van Hove!

Comment: Great. Glad we could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by modifying the Sharing settings for the Contact object. We have updated the Sharing settings of the Contact object and set the `Default Internal Access` to **Public Read/Write** and `Default External Access` to **Private**. Also, updated sharing set that was assigned community portal profile to `User:Contact = Contact:Id`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer to go into a bit more detail? Knowing what, specifically, you changed is likely to help other people with the same or similar issue.